# Are there Windows aplications that can automatically create PDF bookmarks / table of contents?

Tags: windows, pdf

Is there is an application that can automate the creation of table of contents / bookmarks in a pdf file for windows?  Something like [this Mac application](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pdfoutliner/id420874236?mt=12)

Please note, I am asking about creating bookmarks/TOC based on the contents in the pdf file itself. Not creation of bookmarks/TOC from a word document.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Nitro Pro](http://www.nitropdf.com/). I'm a Mac user, but I haven't found an app that can create PDF bookmarks the way Nitro can--so I'm stuck with at least one Windows program. And yes, I've tried PDF Outliner, but it doesn't come close to Nitro. Give it a try...